# Sitecore Publishing slow on Production

Tags: publishing, cms-only

I am working on Sitecore 8.1 update2. Recently I have started facing strange issue on Prod in publishing.

If I publish multiple items together(e.g 4 or 5 etc), it gets stuck and keeps loading but items do not publish. I checked in Logs and found nothing.

If someone faced similar issue regarding publishing, please suggest what can be done to improve publishing functionality.

Comment: Can you please try to truncate the table EventQueue and launch a publish?